# Macros for function composition with no or minimal overhead

Tags: c++, functional-programming, macros, metaprogramming, c++17

Assuming we have a function such as the following:

```
void blax(T t) {
    for {...
            //Stuff
                auto variable = generator(previous_internal_value); 
            //Stuff
    }
}
```

Deeply inside the function lies another function called "generator". The function "blax" could easily be modified to implement another role, lets call this function "blax2".

The only difference in implementation between the two is that 'balx2' uses the function generator2:

```
void blax2(T t) {
    for {...
            //Stuff
                auto variable = generator2(previous_internal_value); 
            //Stuff
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a generic way of writing both functions. What I came up with is something like:

```
    void generic_blax(T t, std::function<int(int)> generator_impl) {
            for {...
                    //Stuff
                        auto variable = generator_impl(previous_internal_value); 
                    //Stuff
            }
        }


void blax(T t) {
    return generic_blax(t, generator)
}

void blax2(T t) {
    return generic_blax(t, generator2)
}
```

This implementation is all well and good but I'm not sure about the efficiency of said code. So my question three fold:

Is there a way to accomplish this function "injection" via a macro, so that I don't have to incur a penalty in nr of functions and nr of function calls at runtime ?

If not, is there a performance penalty incurred from using std::function instead of a function pointer ?

And, is it wise to try and force inlining of 'generic_blax' with the inline keyword in order to obtain performance closer to that which I would have if blax and blax2 had their "normal" function body ? Or will placing inline before 'blax_generic' not inline the function if its too big (even if this would need to happen only in two places) ?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use `std::function<...>`, consider a template. Macros are considered harmful because they behave subtly differently to function calls, but look the same.

```
template <class Generator>
void generic_blax(T t, Generator generator_impl) {
    for {...
        //Stuff
        auto variable = generator_impl(previous_internal_value); 
        //Stuff
        }
    }
```

You don't even have to change your call sites

```
void blax(T t) {
    return generic_blax(t, generator)
}

void blax2(T t) {
    return generic_blax(t, generator2)
}
```

N.B. the keyword inline no longer has *anything to do with* inlining, and it never *forced* it. Link-time optimisations can include inlining across TUs

Comment: I know inline doesn't force inlining, but I assumed it can still "encourage" it... is there a different way to force inlining ? Also,comaping your implementation to the one IIIShamanIII proposed, wouldn't yours resut in extra code (since the function is passed as a parameter, rather than just as the template parameter). ?

Comment: You can't force inlining, besides duplicating the code. It's also a prime example of Knuth's 97% rule: you should trust the compiler to do a good job. For certain workloads an inlined function will be *slower*, as the instruction cache spills are more of a penalty than the `call / ret`

Comment: OK... what about the other question, why is this approach better than just specifying the function as a template parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can relay on inlining, that, most compilers does here.**

If you want guaranteed zero cost for this, you can wrap generator functions into functors & modify code in the following way:

```
template <class Generator>
void generic_blax(T t) {
   for {...
     //Stuff
     auto variable = Generator()(previous_internal_value); 
     //Stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap them in a functor, just take generator_impl as a deduced type instead of std::function

Comment: @Caleth this approach involve same inlining, as code in the question, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm unsure why this is getting downvoted... could somebody care to explain ?